# Difference between two ways of applying $watch in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, watch

I am using service to communicate between the controllers, while using $watch in my controller, i am able to use it in two ways

service.coffee

```
myContent = null

getContent = ->
  return myContent

setContent = (data) ->
  myContent = data
  return myContent
```

my controller:

```
$scope.test = myService

$scope.$watch "test.getContent()", ->
    if $scope.test.getContent() is 'data'
      console.log 'yes'
```

Also,

```
$scope.$watch (->
   test.getContent()
  ), (value) ->
    if value is 'data'
      console.log 'yes'
```

Both gives the expected result, but i would like to know whats the difference between the two methods and in which scenerio we should use the same

Answer (score 0):

Consult the [Angular Documentation on $rootScope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) for a more in-depth answer.

`$scope.$watch()` takes three arguments, where `watchExpression` is the first. `watchExpression` can be either a string or a function. If it is a string, it is evaluated in the `$scope` in question.

This allows us to easily listen to values on the scope:

```
$scope.someValue = 2;
$scope.$watch('someValue', function(someValue) {
    // some function
});
```

In your case, you could simply pass it the function:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.test.getContent, ...);
```

To sum up, pass a function when the result of it is what you want to watch, or pass an expression if that makes more sense (in most cases, it probably will). It makes little sense to pass a string expression evaluating to the result of some function already available, especially taking into account that the expression would have to be parsed, causing an extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

No difference actually. The first parameter of `$watch` function is either a String or a function. If you pass a string as the first parameter for `$watch`, Angular will automatically parse the string into a function taking the `$scope` as the function context.

So you can take the following piece of code

```
$scope.$watch("book", function(){...});
```

as

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.book;}, function(){...});
```

They are internal equivalent.

Comment: Thanks :) but in the case of first approach, when i tried to use variable instead of scope variable, the functionality is not working. I tried to do so since i dont want to use scope variable unless its used in my jade file

Comment: Yes, you are right. First approach can only watch scope variable because the way angular parse it. Approach 2 can watch anything you want for angular won't take further parsing process with the function you passed in. So in every angular digestion loop, the function would be invoked the way you defined it.